# Show/hide content on checkbox

Tags: html, css

i want to hide all content, i want them to show when checked

like show content when checkbox checked

hide when unchecked so that when i check others they show up too

here is my try but its not working

```
<style>
#myBike:not(:checked) +#bike {
  display: block !important;
}

#myCar:not(:checked) +#car {
  display: block !important;
}
</style>

<input type="checkbox" id="myBike">
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCar">
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>

<div class="row" id="bike">
  Something for bike
</div>

<div class="row" id="car">
  Something for car
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot `display: none;`. The `display: block;` style is default for divs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show / hide a specific Div with checkboxes with HTML / CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603161/show-hide-a-specific-div-with-checkboxes-with-html-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the code below.

```css
#bike {
  display: none;
}

#myBike:checked~#bike {
  display: block;
}

#car {
  display: none;
}

#myCar:checked~#car {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myBike" />
<label for="vehicle1">I have a bike</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCar" />
<label for="vehicle2">I have a car</label>

<div class="row" id="bike">Something for bike</div>

<div class="row" id="car">Something for car</div>
```

Expanation:

1. You have used a wrong syntax `~` vs `+`
2. By default all div are set as `display:block`. You should set `display:none` as its initial.